# Why doesn't my script affect my second paragraph element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write some code and I have one issue. Basically I am trying to write some statements (ifs, else etc) and I need to access some `<p>` elements from different `<div>` sections.

```
<body>
    //works with the one below = changes its value from x to 10
    <p id="one" class = "class">x</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var time = new Date().getHours(); 
        if (time < 20) {
            document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = "10";
            document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "10";
        }
    </script>

    <div class="green2">
        <p id ="two" class="class" >x</p>
        //with this one nothing happens
    </div>
```

I guess it doesn't reach the actual element with id `two` so how can I handle it?

Comment: In the third line there shouldn't be this :</div>. Typo sorry

Comment: Nah. I wanna change values from x to 10 in both cases

Comment: script should be below all your body markup or wrap it with DOMContentLOADED event

Comment: The `two` element doesn't yet exist when your script is running, so you can't "reach deeper". You can fix this by placing your script after _all_ of the elements it needs to access, but there are better ways to do this. Any introductory lesson on JavaScript should cover this.

Comment: @JLRishe that's right. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed your code by editing it

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: @NishargShah Do not edit the code in questions to fix the problem the asker is asking about. That just makes the question look nonsensical. If you have a solution to the problem in the question, add your own answer.

Comment: @JLRishe Yep I know that thing but I dont know by doing that OP solve it question, I simply add HTML markup in the question ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is being loaded before the `two`, you should put your `script` tag always at the very bottom of your `body` tags (inside them), so that all your content will be loaded first, only then your script.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Pedro's answer, you can also use jQuery and wrap everything in a document.ready function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var time = new Date().getHours(); 
  if (time < 20) {
    document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = "10";
    document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "10";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="one" class = "class" >x</p>

<div class="green2">
  <p id ="two" class="class" >x</p>
</div>
```

This way you can have the JavaScript appear anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add an event listener such as jQuery's .ready() or javascript's document.onDOMContentLoaded or window.onload events. Then you may place the script where you like and the function will only be executed when the page is ready.

Simply wrap your code in the listener function like such:

```html
<p id="one" class = "class" >x</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var time = new Date().getHours(); 
  if (time < 20) {
    document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = "10";
    document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "10";
  }
});
</script>

<div class="green2">
<p id ="two" class="class" >x</p>
</div>
```